# Google Maps API v3 KML layer from Geoserver doesn't show

Tags: maps, kml, geoserver

Trying to load KML from Geoserver 2.1.1 in Google Maps v3. Nothing shows up. Should this URL work (except with our actual domain)?

```
http://mydomain.org/geoserver/wms/kml?layers=parks_and_recreation:City_Parks_Locations
```

Tried a couple of different layers; same result. I see this response from the Google KmlOverlayService:

```
_xdc_._7hdyfu && _xdc_._7hdyfu( [1] )
```

Comment: did you try opening the KML file in Google Earth?

Comment: I did not try the KML in Google Earth. I played around with the URL. I got the overlay to display the points using the parameter format=geoRSS. Although I hadn't seen any examples using format=kml, I tried it and it works.

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work:

The correct URL:

http://myhost:8080/geoserver/myworkspace/wms/reflect?layers=myworkspace:mylayer&format=kml

(funny I can't find a document to show using "reflect" and "format=kml". Only got the knowledge by googling.)

And myhost:8080 must be accessible to google. Things like "localhost" doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work using this URL.

```
http://mydomain.org/geoserver/wms/reflect?layers=parks_and_recreation:City_Parks_Locations&format=kml
```